# Initialising a dynamically-created btn-group of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am busy writing some helper functions for my fellow developers in-office who isn't too familiar with Bootstrap - which takes basic html and creates bootstrap layouts for them.

In this case, I am trying to make a justified horizontal list of radio buttons.

A example is:

```
    <fieldset data-type="horizontal" data-bootstrap="radiogroup">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="g1" value="default" data-bind="checked: true"/>Recent
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="g1" value="order" data-bind="checked: false"/>By Number
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="g1" value="advanced" data-bind="checked: false"/>Advanced
        </label>
    </fieldset>
```

I execute some JQuery inside the typescript file linked to this page - and the code reads:

```
    function layoutUnwrappedBootstrapControls() {
        $("*[data-bootstrap='radiogroup']")
            .each((index, element) => {
                var listOfRadioButtons = $(element).find('label').clone();
                $(element).children().remove();
                $(element)
                    .append("<div class='btn-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 clearfix' data-toggle='buttons'></div>");
                $(element)
                    .children(":first")
                    .append(listOfRadioButtons)
                    .find("label")
                    .addClass("btn btn-primary")
                    .css("width", (100 / listOfRadioButtons.length) + '%');
                $(element).children(":first").button().button('refresh'); //< the issue   
            });
    }
```

Which produces:

```
<div class="btn-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 clearfix" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 33.3333%;">
        <input type="radio" name="g1" value="default" data-bind="checked: true" data-mini="true" data-theme="h" id="tz15" checked="checked">Recent
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 33.3333%;">
        <input type="radio" name="g1" value="order" data-bind="checked: false" data-mini="true" data-theme="h" id="tz16">By Number
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 33.3333%;">
        <input type="radio" name="g1" value="advanced" data-bind="checked: false" data-mini="true" data-theme="h" id="tz17">Advanced
    </label>
</div>
```

On the page, this seems fine. The issue I have however, is the `data-toggle='buttons'` part - it tells me that bootstrap runs some code in order to initialise the list of radio buttons - and it doesn't seem to play nice with dynamically created button-groups.

My attempt to reinitialise the button group doesn't work. Radio Buttons still remain static - doesn't swap out 'active' on the label, and 'checked' on the input.

The spoopier part is: I cannot reproduce my issue on JSFiddle using identical code! it works as expected on JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpy20jng/3/)

How can I force a re-initialisation of a dynamically-created button-group?

Comment: Make sure that you include the bootstrap js file. You can see that JSFiddle is includeing jquery , bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js . If you do not include the bootstrap.js no error appears in the console, so thats why maybe you missed it.

Comment: Nope, It is on my project though

Comment: Try to disable all scripts&css except bootstrap/jq core and your lines of code. Does it work?

Comment: What is the `data-bind` for? is that for another library like knockout? Hard to help without a demo that actually reproduces your problem

Comment: To clarify: does everything *look* okay (visually) but doesn't have the data you'd expect (i.e. not checked), or does it also look wrong?

Comment: The code might be exactly the same, but in JSFiddle that script is executed when the `onLoad` event is fired. When / how is that script executed on your local server?

Comment: For example, changing the script execution in JSFiddle to "No wrap in head" causes the script to fail: https://jsfiddle.net/amullins/k8qqzcew/2/

Comment: if you cant reproduce your problem that really hard for us, because we can only imagine it. you can try to give us your full code in pastebin if you want.

Comment: "it tells me that bootstrap runs some code in order to initialise the list of radio buttons" are you getting some error in the console?

Comment: Is this an Angular 4 project ? You have mention that this has linked to typescript file.

Comment: @charlietfl It's a knockoutjs binding yes, but it has hardcoded values in. can remove that

Comment: @mynockSpit Nope- it's literally unclickable

Comment: @AustinMullins you have a point why it works on the fiddle. The code does not fire `onload` on my site. It is intended to fire after everything has already been loaded

Comment: @JonathanChaplin No errors in console

Comment: @knetsi, drop your comment as the answer. I want to award the bounty to you.

It turns out that within our framework, we had a <companyname>.bootstrap.js - which confused me. It wasn't Twitter bootstrap.

I never saw the script load once - and that was what was causing the headaches. Added script from cdn - and boom, the code above worked.

Note though : There is a load order. jQuery Mobile/jQueryUI and JQuery must be loaded before bootstrap for this code to work otherwise it causes collisions.. The obvious solution is the hardest to spot...

Comment: @Eon its ok i don't need the reward, you can anwer it yourself and also include the notes about the order you mentioned in the comment, so if someone has similar problem can find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the fact that, as @knetsi mentioned in the comments under the question has mentioned, when you do not have bootstrap.js loaded on your site, you *will not* get an error in the console to point you what the issue was. When, like on my site, you work with both JQuery UI / JQuery Mobile /JQuery and Bootstrap JS, Bootstrap needs to be loaded last - as it *will* cause a conflict with the other libraries when you attempt to refresh a button

Answer (score 4):

If you  call document ready again then previous events associated  using bootstrap.js  will be unbind, which is not a good idea so you can either change the sequence of execution of your script (means before bootstrap.js)  or hold document ready event itself until you are done with your script. You can get reference of jquery.holdready here
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/

Answer (score 3):

If your code executes after bootstrap has already done it's business, it will not work...

You need to make your code execute before bootstrap...

So you need to either,

1. Add your scripts before bootstrap if you are using document ready event.
2. Move your scripts right after your html (in footer) without using document ready event.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me (locally and in a fiddle).

In addition to incorporating `document.ready` in a script tag inside the body (mentioned by previous answers) it looks like your knockout binding has a problem. I changed `checked: true / checked: false` to `checked: statusMsg` and added `statusMsg: ko.observable("default")`. Knockout will check a radio box when the observables value is equal to some radio inputs nodeValue. From the documentation:

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if
>    and only if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value
>   attribute or the value specified by the checkedValue parameter.

[Knockout checked binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)

I logged the `checked` values of the boxes after clicking and it worked.

My code and fiddle below:

```
<body>
<fieldset data-type="horizontal" data-bootstrap="radiogroup">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="g1" value="default" data-bind="checked: statusMsg"/>Recent
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="g1" value="order" data-bind="checked: statusMsg"/>By Number
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="g1" value="advanced" data-bind="checked: statusMsg"/>Advanced
  </label>
</fieldset>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("*[data-bootstrap='radiogroup']")
        .each((index, element) => {
            var listOfRadioButtons = $(element).find('label').clone();
            $(element).children().remove();
            $(element)
                .append("<div class='btn-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 clearfix' data-toggle='buttons'></div>");
            $(element)
                .children(":first")
                .append(listOfRadioButtons)
                .find("label")
                .addClass("btn btn-primary")
                .css("width", (100 / listOfRadioButtons.length) + '%');
        });
    var viewModel = {
        statusMsg: ko.observable("default")
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
</script>
</body>
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/hpy20jng/9/)